# python can't access nonlocal variable before local variable is defined with same name

Tags: python, scope, decorator

I've used decorators before and so I was surprised to find a bug in my code:

```
def make_handler(name, panels):
    def get(self):
        admin = True
        keys = [ndb.Key('Panel', panel) for panel in panels]
        panels = zip(ndb.get_multi(keys), panels)
        panels = [(panel.panel_html if panel else get_default_content(panel_id), panel_id) for panel, panel_id in panels]
        templates = {'panels': panels, 'admin': admin}
        self.render_template('panel_page.html', **templates)
    return type(name, (BaseHandler,), {'get': get})
```

The resulting error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 1536, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 1530, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Robert\PycharmProjects\balmoral_doctors\main.py", line 35, in get
    keys = [ndb.Key('Panel', panel) for panel in panels]
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'panels' referenced before assignment
```

My fix is to change `panel` to `panel2` beyond the first usage:

```
def make_handler(name, panels):
    def get(self):
        admin = True
        keys = [ndb.Key('Panel', panel) for panel in panels]
        panels2 = zip(ndb.get_multi(keys), panels)
        panels2 = [(panel.panel_html if panel else get_default_content(panel_id), panel_id) for panel, panel_id in panels2]
        templates = {'panels': panels2, 'admin': admin}
        self.render_template('panel_page.html', **templates)
    return type(name, (BaseHandler,), {'get': get})
```

This is my understanding: `panels = zip(...)` means that `panels` is a local variable, so the function doesn't look in the outer scope for panels.

This is done before the get() function is run, and not midway through?

I thought it would firstly grab panels from the outer function, and then when panels gets defined in the inner function after that, it would from then on use the new local panels variable.

Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes.**

Python's scoping rules indicate that a function defines a new scope level, and a name is bound to a value in only one scope level in a scope level—it is statically scoped (i.e. all scoping is determined at compilation time). As you understood, you're trying to violate that by reading from a non-local declaration and writing to a local variable. As you observe, the interpreter objects violently to this by raising an `UnboundLocalError`: it has understood that `panels` is a *local* variable (because it can't be that and non-local at the same time), but you haven't assigned (bound) a value to the name, and so it fails.

### More technical details

The decision was made in Python to keep track of where variables are at compilation time in the bytecode (to be specific for this case, it's in a tuple `get.__code__.co_varnames` for local variables), meaning that a variable can be only used in a single scope level in a certain scope. In Python 2.x, it is not possible to modify a non-local variable; you have either read-only access to a global or non-local variable, or read-write access to a global variable by using the `global` statement, or read-write access to a local variable (the default). That's just the way it's been designed (probably for performance and purity). In Python 3, the `nonlocal` statement has been introduced with a similar effect to `global`, but for an intermediate scope.

Binding the modified variable to a different name is the correct solution in this case.

Answer (score 5):

You are more-or-less correct, and you found the correct resolution.  Your problem is equivalent to this:

```
bars = range(10)

def foo():
    thing = [x for x in bars]
    bars = 'hello'

foo()
# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'bars' referenced before assignment
```

At function *definition* time, it is determined that `bars` is local scope. And then at function *run* time, you get the problem that bars hasn't been assigned.

Answer (score 1):

Many people don't realise this, but Python is actually **statically scoped**. When Python sees a read from a bare name (i.e. not an attribute of some object), it can determine *precisely* where that name read will go to purely from compile-time analysis.

If a name is ever assigned to in a function, then that name is a local variable in that function<sup>1</sup>, and it's scope extends over the entirety of the function's body, *even over the lines before the assignment*.

If the name is *not* assigned to in a function, then the name is a non-local variable. Python can check the static scope of any surrounding `def` blocks to see if it's a local variable in any of those. If not, then that name must be a reference to a module global or a built-in (the choice between global and built-in is resolved dynamically, so you *can* shadow a built-in with a global that is declared dynamically).

I believe this is done mainly for efficiently. It means that the set of local variables of a function can be known when the bytecode for the function is compiled, and local variable access can be converted into simple index operations. Otherwise Python would have to perform dictionary lookups to access local variables, which would be slower.

So because your `get` function contains a line of the form `panels = ...`, then `panels` is a local variable in the entirety of the body of `get`. The assignment to `keys` is looping over the local variable `panels` before it has been assigned.

---

<sup>1</sup> Unless that name is declared `global` or `nonlocal`, but that's still statically known.

Answer (score 0):

If a variable is assigned within a function it is assumed to be referring to the local name, unless you explicitly declare it `global` or, in Python 3.x, `nonlocal`. If declared global, the variable must be defined in the module's globals, not covering the above case. You've found one Python 2.x solution; another may be to add `panels` as an argument to `get` and use `functools.partial`:

```
def make_handler(name, panels):
    def get(self, panels):
        admin = True
        keys = [ndb.Key('Panel', panel) for panel in panels]
        panels = zip(ndb.get_multi(keys), panels)
        panels = [(panel.panel_html if panel else get_default_content(panel_id), panel_id) for panel, panel_id in panels]
        templates = {'panels': panels, 'admin': admin}
        self.render_template('panel_page.html', **templates)
    return type(name, (BaseHandler,), {'get': functools.partial(get, panels=panels)})
```

See also: [Closures in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505559/closures-in-python), [Python nonlocal statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261875/python-nonlocal-statement)