# why don't we have closures in python ?

Tags: python, closures

I am learning python. I have read closures in other languages.

But I don't see closures available in python. Is there any particular reason which stops python from having closure in the language ?

Comment: Have you seen the related questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141642/what-limitations-have-closures-in-python-compared-to-language-x-closures?rq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/505559/closures-in-python?rq=1?

Comment: @EdChum Python has [nonlocal](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3104/) now, so maybe the questions (and answers) are a bit dated.